# Javascript: read from url in unicode-escape format

Tags: javascript, unicode-string, node-fetch, unicode-escapes

I am using `node-fetch` to read data from URL. The return result is perfect except it is different from my preferred result.
For some special characters like `í` or this `ř`, I want it instead to be in the format as following: `u00ed` and `u0159`.
Is it possible to achieve something like that without looking up for the character and replacing it manually?

Here is my code:

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
var result = {}
fetch(url)
.then(res => res.json())
.then(json => result = json);
```

My json result:

```
{"title":"Adopce zvířat"}
```

In stead of the result above, I want:

```
{"title":"Adopce zv\\u00ed\\u0159at"}
```

It must be strange but for some reason I want it that way.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow Jane! Could you add the code you are using by editing your question so that we can help you better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `jsesc` package:

> ```js
> const jsesc = require('jsesc');
>
> jsesc('Ich ♥ Bücher'); // → 'Ich \\u2665 B\\xFCcher'
>
> jsesc('foo  bar'); // → 'foo \\uD834\\uDF06 bar'
> ```
>
> *From the [Documentation](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jsesc) on Github*

Answer (score 0):

This funktion from [GitHub Gist User josephrocca](https://gist.github.com/josephrocca) found [here on GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/josephrocca/884cb04e8557e8368a84b8288239a66b) replaces all `non-ASCII` characters  with there unicode escape string.

```
function escapeUnicode(str) {
  return [...str].map(c => /^[\x00-\x7F]$/.test(c) ? c : c.split("").map(a => "\\u" + a.charCodeAt().toString(16).padStart(4, "0")).join("")).join("");
}
```

> This function matches all non-ASCII characters after splitting the
> string in a "unicode-safe" way (using `[...str]`). It then splits each
> unicode character up into its code-points, and gets the escape code
> for each, and then joins all all the ASCII characters and Unicode
> escapes into one string.
>
> [...]
>
> Based on discussion in this thread: https://gist.github.com/mathiasbynens/1243213